# Remove file from a commit in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a commit onto which I have amended some files. Some of these files that were part of the amend I do not want in this commit. Is there a way in Mercurial to remove certain files from the commit without losing the changes I have made to them? Thank you.

Steps:

1. Made some changes
2. hg commit -m
3. Made some more changes (some of these file accidentally amended)
4. hg amend

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try out:

```
hg forget somefile.txt
hg commit --amend
```

If the file was new (i.e. you had used hg add).

If that file already existed try:

```
cp somefile.txt somefile.txt.bak
hg revert somefile.txt --rev .~1
hg commit --amend
```

Which is basically telling mercurial to `revert` the file (`somefile.txt`) back to the state it was one revision ago (`--rev .~1`).

**Just make sure to back up the file you are reverting before entering the command** so that you do not lose your changes. I was under the impression mercurial does this automatically for you, but after testing it quickly I'm not so sure.

Comment: Works like a charm. The `-X somefile.txt` argument does not help if the file was already commited, but reverting the changes to the previous version do the trick.

Comment: I searched before on how to remove a file while amending, and all answered pointed to that it was impossible. This proves them wrong.

Comment: TortoiseHG doesn't seem to be capable of removing all changes from a file in an amend, but clearly `hg` itself has no problem with it.

Answer (score 5):

`hg uncommit somefile.txt` does exactly this for me.

Like plain `git reset`, it removes the change from the commit but leaves the file contents unchanged, so now `hg diff` shows the change you just uncommitted.

The `uncommit` command claims to come from the `uncommit` extension, but may actually be coming from the `evolve` extension, I admit I'm not 100% sure!

Comment: Worked pretty fine.
But, as you said it keeps the content unchanged, so it is necessary to run `hg revert <file>` to discard it.
And, if your commit is in the middle of a thread, it also requires `hg evolve --any` after